# Different variables in different classes that extends from one abstract class in Java

Tags: java, class, abstract

I've got the problem. I want to have 2 classes that extend from 1 abstract class. The problem is these 2 subclasses have different variables, so when I want to create a vector of an abstract class that will contain both subclasses I can't access these variables. Here is an explanation of what I want to do exactly:

```
abstract class Plane {
    protected float x, y;
}

class MilitaryPlane extends Plane {
    private String ammoType;
}

class PassengerPlane extends Plane {
    private int passengersAmount;
}

public static void main() {
    Plane newPlane = new MilitaryPlane;
    newPlane.ammoType = "bomb"; //error: cannot resolve symbol ammoType
}
```

Is there any better thing than casting `newPlane` object into `Plane` class?

Comment: There is no casting in your case. Why not simply declaring the `newPlane` as `MilitaryPlane` since an _abstract plane_ cannot share `ammoType` as a common property?

Comment: Yea, this is wrong example. I write that I want to make a vector of planes and there will be both planes. Or Should I make 2 vectors?

Comment: Construct two planes: `MilitaryPlane militaryPlane` and `PassengerPlace passengerPlane` and initialize/configure them accordingly. Your vector (whatever implementation you'd use) should be only one and declare to use `Plane` only (say, `List<Plane> planes = Arrays.asList(militaryPlane, passengerPlane)` for instance).